# Finding private Key x Big integers

Tags: encryption, key, int, private

Well is it possible to find private key x for this equation y=g^x mod p of course big integers if you have p ,g, y, q?.
What method can be used if there is method to find it out? ..........Note:These are big Integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the discrete logarithm problem. You seem to be interested in the prime field special case of this problem.

For properly chosen fields with sufficiently large `p` this is infeasible. I expect this to be reasonably cheap (100$ or so) for 512 bit `p` and extremely expensive at 1024 bit p. Going beyond that it quicky becomes infeasible even for state level adversaries.

For some fields it's much cheaper. For example solving DL in binary fields (not prime fields as in your example) produced quite a few recent papers. For example [Discrete logarithm in GF(2^809) with FFS](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/197) and [On the Function Field Sieve and the Impact of Higher Splitting Probabilities: Application to Discrete Logarithms in F_2^1971](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/074).

Comment: You still sure there is no other way than these? since i am using very big integers more than 1024

Comment: @NasrAlabdali If everything was done properly, the discrete logarithm problem is hard. But it's possible that your specific set of parameters is weak. A lot of standard and NIST approved cryptography relies on DL being hard. If anybody found a way to compute discrete logarithms on one of the standard prime fields that would be big news.